# Android giving wrong formats for front camera

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a webrtc app and want to resize the local video render view while keeping the aspect ratio. For that I would need the camera width x height format.

I'm getting the front facing camera with

```java
private String getFrontCamera(Camera2Enumerator camera){
    String[] deviceNames = camera.getDeviceNames();
    for (String deviceName : deviceNames) {
        if(camera.isFrontFacing(deviceName)){
            Log.v(TAG, "GETTING FRONT CAMERA"); // this log is fired
            return deviceName;
        }
    }
    // not found front camera, return other
    for (String deviceName : deviceNames) {
        if(!camera.isFrontFacing(deviceName)){
            return deviceName;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

and i use it to create a video track

```java
private VideoTrack createVideoTrack(){
    Camera2Enumerator camera = new Camera2Enumerator(this.appContext);
    String cameraName = this.getFrontCamera(camera);

    this.localVideoCapturer = camera.createCapturer(cameraName, null);

    // .......

    List<CameraEnumerationAndroid.CaptureFormat> formats = camera.getSupportedFormats(cameraName);
    // get format with the biggest height
    CameraEnumerationAndroid.CaptureFormat cameraFormat = this.bestCameraFormat(formats);
    this.updateRendererLayout(cameraFormat);
    this.localVideoCapturer.startCapture(cameraFormat.width, cameraFormat.height, 30);
}
```

Camera2Enumerator has a Log built in that function that gives

```
// Logging.d("Camera2Enumerator", "Format: " + size.width + "x" + size.height + "@" + maxFps);
Camera2Enumerator: Get supported formats for camera index 1.
Camera2Enumerator: Format: 2576x1932@30000
Camera2Enumerator: Format: 2560x1440@30000
Camera2Enumerator: Format: 2048x1536@30000
Camera2Enumerator: Format: 2048x1152@30000
Camera2Enumerator: Format: 1920x1920@30000
Camera2Enumerator: Format: 1920x1080@30000
Camera2Enumerator: Format: 1440x1080@30000
Camera2Enumerator: Format: 1280x720@30000
Camera2Enumerator: Format: 1072x1072@30000
Camera2Enumerator: Format: 960x720@30000
Camera2Enumerator: Format: 720x480@30000
Camera2Enumerator: Format: 640x480@30000
Camera2Enumerator: Format: 352x288@30000
Camera2Enumerator: Format: 320x240@30000
Camera2Enumerator: Format: 256x144@30000
Camera2Enumerator: Format: 176x144@30000
Camera2Enumerator: Get supported formats for camera index 1 done. Time spent: 46 ms.
```

This coincides with my output, but this can't be right because:
- width is bigger that height on all formats - this is the front camera, portrait
- fps is 30000

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: I also need a similar thing, have you find any solution?